# Python Requests: Logging into Microsoft.com but getting logged out

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to login to `Microsoft.com` at this [URL](https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?wa=wsignin1.0). I recieve a `200 OK` from the server. This is all in a python requests session by the way. However, when I go to another URL, for instance `account.xbox.com`, it does not let me log in and redirects me to the login page. I don't expect to be spoon-fed, but how do I find the cookies needed to say I've logged in, especially if I'm already in a session.

Edit: I think the problem is with 3rd party cookies. This the the response page message:

> We can't sign you in
>       Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service.
>       Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell us when you're signed in. To learn how to allow cookies, check the online
>   help in your web browser.

Edit 2: added code

```
login_form = {
'i13': 0,
'login': 'username',
'loginfmt': 'username,
'type': 11,
'LoginOptions': 3,
'passwd': 'passowrd',
'ps': 2,
'PPFT': 'DT7FcXvu1j5UZEuAijgCbCFp2h4S18Jax305PmmXq4RBn2umUYQdCHR4s56Hz4aXynR8ZMa5QFNZuV00lZuXeeafX5A5wOinjHd2FH1p*uqD3SC99!Axsw4MPfAYpMiWmMT*!9bn68afs*06auhdEfEgar2hAZb4h9ojYTsffyfsBJ*d2OylwhjssZ5tyYKmKSesCwz22NMgxA1iQtnoB7e372A3PEGXX96ZdnyttvGwfJc2DDYxSINr!MiBZ06BhQ$$',
'PPSX': 'P',
'NewUser': 1,
'fspost': 0,
'i21': 0,
'CookieDisclosure': 0,
'IsFidoSupported': 1,
'i2': 1,
'i17': 0,
'i18': '__ConvergedLoginPaginatedStrings|1,__OldConvergedLogin_PCore|1,__OldConvergedLogin_PAlt|1,',
'i19': 18430,
}

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie': 'CkTst=G1533539730122; uaid=560f12860bcc490b96b2b47b59d279b5; MSPRequ=lt=1533584411&id=292543&co=1; CkTst=G1533584432775; MSPOK=$uuid-a0d2394b-38e2-41f6-a594-75d2f6cd22e6$uuid-61ba4660-7580-4c5e-8efe-3b9b6a393c9e$uuid-5dddd33a-bf32-4b7e-9d55-fca1049943f9$uuid-92fc9fdc-b8ed-48bb-950d-7e5d0aa41417; wlidperf=FR=L&ST=1533584441597',
    'Content-Length': '722',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host': 'login.live.com',
    'Origin': 'https://login.live.com',
    'Referer': 'https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&rver=6.7.6643.0&wp=SA_20MIN&wreply=https:%2f%2faccount.xbox.com%2fen-US%2fChangeGamertag&lc=1033&id=292543&aadredir=1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36',
}
```

This is to log in at https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf?wa=wsignin1.0, returns 200 ok, but going to this link, https://account.xbox.com/en-us
seems to log me out, or require me to log in again?

Comment: It would be better if we could see your code!

Comment: I added  the relevant code!

Comment: are you using a requests session to maintain cookies?

Comment: Yessir, I initiate one and use that for post and get requests

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft responds with a 200 even if your login session is denied. output the text into an html file and open it in a browser to see the response. Also your cookies could be expired. You should be logging into the server in your session as well